# Configuring apache to run in minimal memory

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, tuning

I have a micro instance of Ec2 with Django connected to apache via wsgi. Whenever I hit the server httpd hits top of the CPU and memory cycle and page consequently take some time to load.

Can someone help me tweak apache so that it does not consume a lot of memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing unnecessary modules, for example if you don't need python or perl you can remove:

```
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
```

From the configuration files.